# How to set type from a object of interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Below is my code

```
interface platformItem {
    Result: {
         name: string;
         age: number;
    };
}

const man: platformItem.Result;
```

The vscode will show warning which is no export member from platformItem, seems I can not use platformItem.result.

Comment: What is `platformItem.Result` supposed to mean?

Comment: means the man should has  name and age.

Answer (score 2):

this work for me on vscode `platformItem['Result']`

Comment: That is the correct code. It is known as an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here are three different approaches. [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Normal%0D%0Ainterface%20platformItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Result%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20const%20man%3A%20platformItem%5B%22Result%22%5D%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Max%20Power%22%2C%20age%3A%2030%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Typ%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20Man%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20platformItem%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20Result%3A%20Man%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20man%3A%20Man%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Max%20Power%22%2C%20age%3A%2030%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Mixing%0D%0A%2F%2F%20namespace%20platformItem%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20export%20type%20Result%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20platformItem%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20Result%3A%20platformItem.Result%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20man%3A%20platformItem.Result%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Max%20Power%22%2C%20age%3A%2030%20%7D%3B)

[Indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
interface platformItem {
    Result: {
         name: string;
         age: number;
    };
}

 const man: platformItem["Result"] = { name: "Max Power", age: 30 };
```

[Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
type Man = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
};

interface platformItem {
    Result: Man;
}

const man: Man = { name: "Max Power", age: 30 };
```

[Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

```
namespace platformItem {
    export type Result = {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    };
}
interface platformItem {
    Result: platformItem.Result;
}

const man: platformItem.Result = { name: "Max Power", age: 30 };
```